# How to find a link that has text nested in a div with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to find a link in my navbar, nested like so:

```
<div class="menu logged-out" id="loggedoutmenu">
  <a href="/users/auth/twitter?state=navbar_basic" data-no-instant>
    <div class="option"> via Twitter</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I've tried using the following methods and none of them have worked:

- `find_link("via Twitter")`
- `find_link("via Twitter", {href: "/users/auth/twitter?state=navbar_basic"})`
- `find('div', {class: 'option'})`

Not really sure how to grab that element... The main goal is to test the link via `click_link`.

Edit:
Here's the full HTML structure:

```
<body>
 <div class="top-bar" id="top-bar">
   <nav>
    <--- other nav elements not listed --->
    <div class="navigation-butt desktop" id="navigation-butt"> 
      <div class="menu logged-out" id="loggedoutmenu">
        <a href="/users/auth/twitter?state=navbar_basic" data-no-instant>
          <div class="option"> via Twitter</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't you just do `find('.option')` ?

Comment: Is that link actually visible on the page when you're trying to locate it, or is it hidden in a menu that you need to perform some other action before it becomes visible?  If it is actually visible on the page any of the examples you showed should find elements.  Also, show the actual errors you get with the things you've tried when posting questions.

Comment: And if you're going to click the parent `<a>` - which is a bit weird html structure to say the least, probably `find('.menu a').click` or `first('.menu a').click` are better options. And as @ThomasWalpole mentioned making sure the menu is there is also necessary...

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer recommending beginners use `first` is asking for problems.  Too many people rely on `first` without understanding the issues it has which leads to flaky tests and frustration.  A better suggestion would be `find('.menu a:first-child')` if not using the `find/click_link` methods.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole you might be right, but frustration is a great enabler for understanding a problem - said no one ever - I should have added that after clicking a link you should always assert you get where you expect to get in order to not flop the test purpose though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Writing my solution as an extension of Thomas Walpole's, which lead me to getting it. Thanks again, Thomas!

```
find('#navigation-butt').hover.click_link(href:"/users/auth/twitter?state=navbar_basic")
```

Edit: Updated my answer since the previous explanation was incorrect.

Comment: Got it. Updated my answer to reflect your comment. Also, for the record omitting the parameter works. Just because I want to figure out what's happening: do you think because the navbar button is a hover element the inner div with the text "via Twitter" is therefore non-visible, as you alluded to?

Comment: Not knowing what CSS is applied makes it hard to know, but guesses would be you have CSS that’s changing the case of the text, or you’re hiding the text and replacing it with a logo image. It just being in a div in the link would not stop Capybara from seeing it

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the menu is collapsed and you haven't done anything to open it, so the link isn't actually visible on the page.  Assuming you just need to click on the '#loggedoutmenu' item to open the menu you could do something like

```
find('#loggedoutmenu').click.click_link('via Twitter')
```

which will click on 'loggedoutmenu' then look for the link inside it, and click the link when found.  If clicking on '#loggedoutmenu' isn't how you open the menu then you'll need to provide more info.

Update: You have now indicated that the menu opens on hover - so assuming the user has to hover over an ancestor of the button you want to click you can do

```
 find('<css selector for the visible element the user needs to hover over>').hover.click_link('via Twitter')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Definitely on the right track here. It's an "on-hover" menu. I managed to get to the button via: `find('#navigation-butt')`. Is there a method that shows all the children of that element? That way I would have a better understanding of what Capybara is seeing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PandyZhao Not really, and since you don't show an element with id of 'navigation_butt' in your question it's impossible to know what you're actually doing/finding.  Capybara is "seeing" exactly what a user would see on the page, and you need to perform the actions a user would need to perform.  So if a user needs to hover over an element in order to be able to click on the 'via Twitter' button, then find that element and call `#hover` on it. Also, show everything needed by people to help you in the original question.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I edited my question with the necessary HTML.

Comment: @PandyZhao Ok - so `find('#navigation-butt').hover.click_link('via Twitter')`If that's the element that needs to be hovered over.

Comment: I ended up making it work, as per my solution below. Thanks again for all the help!